# Dynamic meta tag content in Cordova Content-Security-Policy

Tags: angularjs, cordova

The following code works just fine since I added https://mobileapppractice.azurewebsites.net in meta tag to prevent violate CSP.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-init="backendUri='https://mobileapppractice.azurewebsites.net'">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    
    <title>Kapok Practice</title>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/MobileServices.Web-2.0.0-beta.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/appBundle.js"></script>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://mobileapppractice.azurewebsites.net data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    
    <!-- BlankCordovaApp2 references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <p>Hello, your application is ready! </p>
    

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, in the following line, https://mobileapppractice.azurewebsites.net is hard coded in the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://mobileapppractice.azurewebsites.net ...
```

so I want to use angularJS expression to make this url dynamic in meta tag, ex:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' {{"https://mobileapppractice.azurewebsites.net"}} ...
```

However, it didn't work and shows error "...violate Content Security Policy" when it try to invoke the WebAPI in https://mobileapppractice.azurewebsites.net.

Is there an easy way to how to make this CSP meta tag support angularJS dynamic control?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this would be practical, you are basically setting the policy... ***after page has loaded*** which means  prior to then anything that is being blacklisted has already had a chance to be loaded already

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I think we have to hard code the url definition in CSP.
or Is there any configurable way to do it? Since I got test, staging and production WebAPI url which are totally different. 
Do I need to hard code them all in the meta tag of CSP?