# Modify <meta> tag with JS (chrome extension) on response receiving

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, meta-tags, content-security-policy

I have a Chrome extension that adds a panel to the page in the floating iframe (on extension button click). There's certain JS code that is downloaded from 3rd party host and needs to be executed on that page. Obviously there's XSS issue and extension needs to comply with content security policies for that page.

Previously I had to deal with CSP directives that are passed via request headers, and was able to override those via setting a hook in `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`. There I was adding my host URL to `content-security-policy` headers. It worked. Headers were replaced, new directives applied to the page, all good.

Now I discovered websites that set the CSP directives via `<meta>` tag, they don't use request headers. For example, app pages in iTunes https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/olympics/id808794344?mt=8 have such. There is also an additional meta tag with name `web-experience-app/config/environment` (?) that somewhat duplicates the values that are set in content of tag with `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`.

This time I am trying to add my host name into meta tag inside `chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted` or `onCompleted` events listeners (JS vanilla via `chrome.tabs.executeScript`). I also experimented with running the same code from the webrequest's `onCompleted` listener (at the last step of lifecycle according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest).

When I inspect the page after its load - I see the meta tags have changed. But when I click on my extension to start loading iframe and execute JS - console prints the following errors:

`Refused to frame 'https://myhost.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' *.apple.com itmss: itms-appss: itms-bookss: itms-itunesus: itms-messagess: itms-podcasts: itms-watchs: macappstores: musics: apple-musics:".`

I.e. my tag update was not effective.

I have several questions: first, do I do it right? Am I doing the update at the proper event? When is the data content from meta tags being read in the page lifecycle? Will it be auto-applied after tag content change?

Comment: A bit of a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799561/dynamic-meta-tag-content-in-cordova-content-security-policy
In my question though there is an assumption the extension's JS code can change <meta> tag before the page parsing starts. Or is `chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted` too late of a step for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 2018 Chromium doesn't allow to modify the responseBody of the request. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422#c29

"WebRequest API: allow extensions to read response body" is a ticket from 2015. It is not on a path of getting to be resolved and needs some work/help.

--

Firefox has the webRequest filter implementation that allows to modify the response body before the page's meta directives are applied. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData
BUT, my problem is focused on fixing the Chrome extension. Maybe Chrome picks this up one day.

--

In general, the Chrome's extension building framework seems like not a reliable path of building a long term living software; with browser vendors changing the rules frequently, reacting to newly discovered threats, having no up-to-date supported cross-browser standard.

--

In my case, the possible way around this issue can be to throw all the JS code into the extension's source base. Such that there's no 3-rd party to connect to fetch and execute the JS (and conflict with/violate the CSP rules). Haven't explored this yet, as I expected to reuse the code & interactive components I am using in my main browser application.

Answer (score 0):

I've been interested in the same things and here are a few aspects that perhaps could help:

1. chrome.debugger extension API with Fetch (or Network) domain can be used to modify responseBody: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/
   This is an example implementation: https://github.com/mr-yt12/Debugger-API-Fetch-example-Chrome-Extension
   However, I'm facing a problem of Fetch.requestPaused not firing on the first page load: [Chrome Extension Debugger API, Fetch domain attaches/enables too late for the response body to be intercepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232136/chrome-extension-debugger-api-fetch-domain-attaches-enables-too-late-for-the-re)
   And I haven't found a solution to this yet, besides first redirecting the request to 'http://google.com/gen_204' and then updating the tab. But this creates flicker and also I'm not sure if it's possible to redirect the request like this with manifest v3.
2. When using debugger API, Chrome shows a warning at the top, which changes the page's size and doesn't go away (perhaps it goes away 5 seconds after the debugger is detached and also if the user clicks "cancel"). This means that it's mostly only good for personal use or when distributing as a developer mode extension. Using `--silent-debugger-extension-api` flag with Chrome disables this warning.
3. I've tried injecting my script at document_start (when the meta tag is not yet created). Then I used mutationObserver (also tried other methods) to wait for the meta tag, to modify it before it's applied or fully created. Somehow it succeeded once or a few times, but could be a coincidence or a wrong interpretation of results. Perhaps it's worth experimenting with it.
4. Another idea (but I think I didn't make it work, but perhaps it's possible) is to use `window.stop()` at `document_start` and then rewrite the html content programmatically. This needs more researching.
5. It seems that meta tag CSP is applied once the meta tag is created (or while it's being created), and then there is no way to cancel what's been applied. It should be researched more on how to prevent it from applying or modifying it before it's fully created or applied.