# Chrome Extension Debugger API, Fetch domain attaches/enables too late for the response body to be intercepted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm intercepting a response body of a document/script using debugger API to modify it and continue the request.

The current flow is:

1. adding webRequest.onBeforeRequest listener (I've tried webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate as well)
2. when the request occurs, redirecting it to 'http://google.com/gen_204'.
3. attaching debugger to the tab.
4. calling `chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: details.url })`
5. Waiting for the `Fetch.requestPaused` event:

```
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener((debuggeeId, method, frameId) => {
  if (method === "Fetch.requestPaused") {
    console.log('fetch requestPaused', performance.now() - time); 
//modifying the request and fulfilling it
```

```
let time = 0;
let objectOfTabsToStop = {}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  (details) => {
    if (!/^https:\/\/(website\.com)$/.test(details.url)) return;
    let tabId = details.tabId;
    let debuggeeId = { tabId: tabId };
    if (objectOfTabsToStop[tabId] && 
    objectOfTabsToStop[tabId].debugger === true) {
console.log('webRequest second time', performance.now() - time);
      return;
    }
    console.log('webRequest first time', 0); time = performance.now();
    objectOfTabsToStop[tabId] = { stop: true, debugger: false };
    chrome.debugger.attach(debuggeeId, '1.3', () => {
      console.log('debugger attached', performance.now() - time);
      objectOfTabsToStop[tabId].debugger = true;
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
        debuggeeId, "Debugger.enable", {},
        () => {
          console.log('debugger enabled', performance.now() - time);
          chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
            debuggeeId,
            "Fetch.enable",
            {
              patterns: [{
                requestStage: "Response",
                resourceType: "Document", urlPattern: '*website*'
              },
              {
                requestStage: "Response",
                resourceType: "Script", urlPattern: '*website*'
              }]
            },
            () => {
              console.log('fetch enabled', performance.now() - time);
              objectOfTabsToStop[tabId].stop = false;
              chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: details.url })
            });
        });
    });
    return { redirectUrl: 'http://google.com/gen_204' }
  },
  {
    urls: ["https://website.com/*"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

If I don't redirect to 'http://google.com/gen_204' the webpage continues to load and "Fetch.requestPaused" for `Document` doesn't fire until the page is reloaded (it only fires for one of the scripts, because it's a different request). Apparently it takes too long for Fetch/Debugger to be enabled?

Here are the time measurements:

- webRequest first time 0
- debugger attached 0.9999999892897904
- debugger enabled 19.00000000023283
- fetch enabled 22.999999986495823
- webRequest second time (after `chrome.tabs.update` has been executed) 35.00000000349246
- fetch requestPaused 108.00000000745058 (Document)
- fetch requestPaused 266.00000000325963 (Script)
- fetch requestPaused 340.99999998579733 (Script)

I've tried it with the `Network` domain as well and got the same result.

I'm wondering if there is any better way of doing this, without redirecting to 'http://google.com/gen_204' first.

Comment: I've created a bug report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1281081